# Calling web service from JQuery and redirect the response data(XML) to Web Api controller

Tags: jquery, xml, web-services

I have a following question :
I need to call public web service which is responsing with XML data format and this response (XML data) need to be send to Web Api controller.
At the moment I have self hosted my Web Api as windows service and I can call it from JQuery. I`m able to call the service but totally not sure how to take the response(XML data) and make another call within the same request.
This is my sample code a function(called on click button) to call the web service.At this time i need to take the response(XML) and send it to my Web Api

```
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'SampleService.com',
            complete: function (xData) {
                $('#txt').html($(xData.responseXML).text()); // result
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: have you tried using ajax but with POST method?

Comment: which API is suppose to recieve your XML data? Laravel, Nodejs ?

Comment: @HenryDev ASP.NET Web API.It should be POST I know but how to re-send the the response which is including XML data to ASP.NET Web API controller